# How can I put a clickable URL in my VF page

Tags: visualforce, url

if I gather the url of a record that I want to direct a user to, how can I display this URL as a clickable URL in a VF Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

[apex output link](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputLink.htm)

You could also use the URLFOR with [$Action](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action.htm) Global variable

Answer (score -1):

You can use outputLink or outputField